# Can't include mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, netbeans

I have been trying for a while now. I have been asked to do a few modifications on a big program, and it requires a lot of libs. All of them were succesfully added, except mysql.

I downloaded the libs several times and tried a lot of times.

I am on Windows using Netbeans and C++.

The test I decided to do is simple: create an empty program and try to include mysql. I didn't have any success:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

This program won't work even if I replace `#include <mysql/mysql.h>` with  `#include <mysql.h>`.

The error NetBeans gives me is the following:

> main.cpp:15:25: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory

These images show how I altered the project options on Linker and C/C++ options:

[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn9ZW.png)

The folder showing on the C image does contain a mysql.h, i triple checked twice.
I also have added the paths with includes to CodeAssistance.
Many similar questions were left unanswered for years now on several forums, even on stackoverflow, and I can't seem to work this out. This thread may have a final answer to those of us who stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find the file

At this point, your program would be pointing to something like this:

```
cl /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"
mysql1.c
```

So you needed to include the directory that contains mysql.h as well. So the above would changed to:

```
cl /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" 
/I "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include" mysql1.c
```

Comment: Manually adding the include path like "../../../../C:\MySQL\include" solved the include problem, but several others appeared. I resolved all of these manually in hope it would work, but I ended up with this error:
'make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target `/C/Program Files \(x86\)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib/libmysql.lib', needed by `dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/program.exe'.  Stop.'

Clearly, this is a bigger problem somehow, and this workaround doesn't fix it 100%

Answer (score 0):

verify the header file exist in the path /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h or installed some where else. If you have installed the header files somewhere else ( add that location with -I/.

Comment: I am very sure the file is there, and it is correctly stated in the -I command.